# PHP+JSON Webservice - Leitura array

Tags: php, json

Gostaria de interpretar um *JSON* com *PHP*, onde:

```
{"data":
  {
    "nome1":João,
    "status":["Ativo"]
  }
}

$retorno = json_decode($jsonRet);

$nome1 = $retorno->data->nome1;
$status = $retorno->data->status;

echo "nome1: ".$nome1." / ".$status;die;
```

O `nome1`, consigo ler dessa forma normalmente, mas o *status* que está entre colchetes não funciona, retorna sem nada...

Como seria para ler corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chave `status` é um `array`, para acessá-la você deve informar o índice que deseja obter. No seu caso, como só há um índice, é acessível por:

```
$status = $retorno->data->status[0];
```

Comment: Resolvido, Obrigado!!!